# How to call UITableview datasource(cellForRowAt) when its added into UITableViewCell content view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm displaying the list of data in UITableView(tableview1). In the cell of tableview1. I am adding another UITableView(tableview2).The problem is 'cellForRowAt' for tableview2 is not getting call but 'numberOfRowsInSection' is getting call all the time.

Please check tableview1 cell class. Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in this. I am stuck on this from last 2 days . I have tried every solution but its not working.

I have tried solutions as given below :

[Is it possible to add UITableView within a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17398058/is-it-possible-to-add-uitableview-within-a-uitableviewcell)

[UITableView inside UITableViewCell with dynamic height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46441711/uitableview-inside-uitableviewcell-with-dynamic-height)

I have to add tableview into another tableviewcell but right now 'cellForRowAt' of another tableview is not getting call.

Below code I have used for tableview1 cell class

```
import UIKit

class abcCell: UITableViewCell {

    var myTableView: UITableView!
    let cellId = "nextTableCellId"

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        setupView()
        myTableView.reloadData()
        }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.numberOfLines =  0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.text = "Next table:"
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        return label
        }()

    func setupView() {
        myTableView = UITableView()
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.separatorStyle = .singleLineEtched
        myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        myTableView.isScrollEnabled = false

        addSubview(myTableView)
        addSubview(label)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", views: myTableView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", views: label)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 15))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myTableView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
    }
}


extension abcCell: UITableViewDelegate {

}

extension abcCell: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CartSubTableCell
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }
}

extension UIView {
    func addConstraintsWithFormat(_ format: String, views: UIView...) {
        var viewsDictionary = [String: UIView]()
        for (index, view) in views.enumerated() {
            let key = "v\(index)"
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            viewsDictionary[key] = view
        }
        addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: format, options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: viewsDictionary))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After, adding frame of 'myTableView' everything is working fine.

```
 func setupView() {
        myTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:self.frame.size.width, height:self.frame.size.height), style: .plain)
        myTableView.delegate = self
        myTableView.dataSource = self
        myTableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        myTableView.backgroundColor = .red
        addSubview(myTableView)
        addSubview(label)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", views: myTableView)
        addConstraintsWithFormat("H:|-30-[v0]-30-|", views: label)

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 15))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTableView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: label, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: myTableView, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myTableView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -15))
    }
```